# Saleor 3 's rendering is much slower than 2.11

Tags: saleor

I clone saleor 2.11 and it renders very fast.

But when I switch to version 3, it becomes much slower.

It needs more than 1s to serve a request (1.3 or 1.6s), v2.11 only needs less than 0.5s.

All tests are run on my local machine.

Can anybody tell me why - and how to fix this?

Thank you so much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.